# Matomo(piwik) Configuration in Windows Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, single-page-application, matomo, piwiktracker

We are currently trying to track the website which is hosted on apache springboot and is a single page application. We pasted the auto generated code in the index.html page as required. But, once logged in with the superuser in the Matomo analytics (on premise) in the windows virtual machine , it asks us to test the website which is supposed to track. Once we try , it results with an error saying "**Tracking code verification failed. Please verify that you have installed the code correctly**".

[Matomo Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyyd0.png)

We tried multiple scenarios. We tried changing the hostname in the config.ini.php file in the matomo path under httpd folder. Hostname we tried configuring as the same name as our VM's hostname.
We expect that this error should not come and it tests successfully and takes us to the dashboard of the Matomo analytics tool.